# Fail to open iOS app using Flutter + Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am setting up Firebase to a Flutter app. I finished the setup for Android and saw traffic on Firebase Analytics dashboard. However, the iOS version crashes with the message shown below. Could you give me any ideas?

1. I downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist` from Firebase UI and used `mv` command to move it to `ios/Runnder` directory.
2. I added `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` to `ios/Podfile` and run `pod install`. (At this point, I opened iOS simulator via Android Studio and confirmed the app ran without problems.)
   [image]
3. I added two rows to `ios.Runnder.AppDelegate.swift`.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase // Added!!!

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    FirebaseApp.configure() // Added!!!
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

4. Then I tried to run the app on iOS simulator again and this error message was shown on Android Studio.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           39.5s
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8527e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010caf2b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc850bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x000000010991c9ea +[FIRApp configure] + 138
    4   Runner                              0x0000000109917ca4 $s6Runner11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtF + 212
    5   Runner                              0x0000000109917ff4 $s6Runner11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtFTo + 21<…>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the you can't simply move the **GoogleService-Info.plist** into the ios/Runner directory, you have to add it within the xcode project for it to be recognized. To do this, open the xcode project for the app, right click the Runner directory and select **Add Files to "Runner" as shown below. Then navigate to where your GoogleService-Info.plist was downloaded and select it to add it to the project.

[image: Screenshot of xcode Add Files to Runner]

Comment: Great, glad I could help. If this fixed your issue would you mind accepting the answer so the question is closed?